# Url Rewrite of a CMS page in Magento

Tags: magento

As a new magento developer I'm using a theme to develop my store. I want to change the URL key of CMS page *about*. I followed the steps written [here](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-change-cms-pages-and-system-pages-url-aliases.html) but I can't find my layout file for *about* page on the theme directory or base directory for change XML URL tag.

How can I edit the layout file? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Actually that tutorial is a little confusing because there, they are showing an example of changing a URL for two different type of pages (CMS and system).

For changing the URL of a CMS page, like *about* in your case, it's enough that you proceed until point 12. In short:

> First. you change the URL from: (main menu) CMS/Pages/Your_Page -> Url Key: newURL
>
> Then, find the blocks that it is used (e.g footer) and change the URL accordingly.

Plus, in general working in Magento after changing things like page URLs you need to do a reindex and in case of using cache you have to refresh/remove your cached data. Both could be found under System tab (Cache Management & Index Management).